# Права доступа Apache2 777

Tags: linux, apache2, chmod

На локалке поднят *apache2*, для сайтов/тестов использую директорию `/home/www/`

Там расположены следующие каталоги с правами 777:

```
alice@alice:/home/www$ ls -la
drwxrwxrwx  6 www-data www-data 4096 июл 13 00:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root     4096 июн 10 01:29 ..
drwxrwxrwx  8 alice    alice    4096 июл 12 10:56 calendar
drwxrwxrwx 14 alice    alice    4096 июл 12 09:47 lara
drwxrwxrwx 13 alice    alice    4096 июн 28 00:24 laravel
drwxrwxrwx 12 alice    alice    4096 июл 13 00:26 onepage
```

перейдем в директорию проекта:

```
alice@alice:/home/www$ cd calendar/
alice@alice:/home/www/calendar$ ls -la
drwxrwxrwx 8 alice    alice    4096 июл 12 10:56 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data 4096 июл 13 00:08 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     305 июн 12 17:53 bower.json
drwxrwxrwx 7 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 components
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     584 июн 12 17:53 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     372 июн 12 17:53 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxrwx 2 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    1742 июн 12 17:53 events.json.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    1076 июн 12 17:53 Gruntfile.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 alice    alice    4096 июл 12 07:34 .idea
drwxrwxrwx 2 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    3497 июл  8 03:36 index-bs3.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    3160 июл  8 03:12 index.html
drwxrwxrwx 3 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 js
drwxrwxrwx 2 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 less
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    1080 июн 12 17:53 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     614 июн 12 17:53 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    9047 июн 12 17:53 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     188 июн 12 17:53 web.config
```

Cоздадим файл `new.php`:

```
alice@alice:/home/www/calendar$ touch new.php
alice@alice:/home/www/calendar$ ls -la
drwxrwxrwx 8 alice    alice    4096 июл 13 03:00 .
drwxrwxrwx 6 www-data www-data 4096 июл 13 00:08 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     305 июн 12 17:53 bower.json
drwxrwxrwx 7 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 components
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     584 июн 12 17:53 composer.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     372 июн 12 17:53 CONTRIBUTING.md
drwxrwxrwx 2 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    1742 июн 12 17:53 events.json.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    1076 июн 12 17:53 Gruntfile.js
drwxrwxrwx 3 alice    alice    4096 июл 12 07:34 .idea
drwxrwxrwx 2 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    3497 июл  8 03:36 index-bs3.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    3160 июл  8 03:12 index.html
drwxrwxrwx 3 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 js
drwxrwxrwx 2 alice    alice    4096 июл  8 03:07 less
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    1080 июн 12 17:53 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 alice    alice       0 июл 13 03:00 new.php
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     614 июн 12 17:53 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice    9047 июн 12 17:53 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 alice    alice     188 июн 12 17:53 web.config
```

Почему новосозданному файлу `new.php` права присваиваются 644?

Как это исправить ?

Зы: надоело набирать `chmod -R 777 ./*`

Comment: *надоело набирать chmod -R 777 ./\** — очень похоже на [проблему неверной постановки задачи](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710/178576)

Comment: создание пользователем **всех** файлов и каталогов с правами `ugo=rwx` — это неправильное решение. равно как и присвоение всем файлам/каталогам в docroot-е таких прав. по-моему, корень проблемы в том, что http-сервер у вас работает от имени пользователя, отличного от того, кому принадлежат файлы/каталоги в docroot-е. решать стоит именно эту проблему, а не последствия попытки решить её неправильно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , на просторах сети нашел следующий совет 
Есть такой модуль apache2-mpm-itk, он позволяет запускать VirtualHost от имени отдельного пользователя. С учетом этого модуля структура папок на мой взгляд должна выглядеть так:
1.) /var/www - права 755, пользователь www-data, группа www-data
2.) /var/www/domains - права 755, пользователь www-data, группа www-data(пользователь по умолчанию в apache)
3.) /var/www/domains/domain1.com - права 700, пользователь user-domain1, группа www-data
4.) права у файлов и папок 700

Comment: это не совсем ответ. это лишь предположение о том, что на самом деле требуется. вероятно, требуется какому-то «рядовому» пользователю исправлять/создавать файлы/каталоги в *docroot-е*. правильнее решать такую задачу с помощью групповой принадлежности. если я угадал, то напишите об этом, пожалуйста, я постараюсь описать рекомендации в ответе (поискал правильное (с моей точки зрения) решение среди ответов на аналогичные вопросы, но, увы, не нашёл).

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос представляет собой типичную «[ошибку иксигрек](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576)»: вместо устранения проблемы — попытка исправить последствия её неверного «решения».

Comment: @NickVolynkin, боюсь, что вопрос о том, как лучше восстановить содранную с микроскопа краску, превратить в вопрос о том, чем надо забивать гвозди, можно разве только полным переписыванием.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, «по уму», надо бы написать талмуд о хорошей методе разработки веб-сайтов, в частности затронув и такие практики, как запуск дочерних процессов сервера от имени другого пользователя и (у *apache*) даже от многих разных пользователей. но я за такой труд не возьмусь, да он и «не в формате» сайта. вот если эти проблемы как-то по кусочкам осветить и собрать под одной меткой — это было бы неплохо.

Comment: Мне вот что не понятно: у вас же в листинге видно, что файлу дали права 644. Такие права не должны помешать веб-серверу прочитать его. Почему же вы пишете, что ему якобы достались права 700?

Comment: Извиняюсь, ошибся -  конечно , 644.</br>
Ребят , давайте не будем устраивать голосования в топике .</br>
Попробую перефразировать вопрос.
Объясните , почему при создании файла пользователем в директории /home/www/bla-bla права на запись в файл даются только root-y ? Возможно , тут как-то можно решить данный вопрос средствами Apache2 или ,возможно, просто изменением групповай политике (тип пользователь что в группе www_data имеет права на запись в файл *домыслы*).
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

вам надо согласовать принадлежность файлов в *docroot*-е и пользователя, от имени которого *apache* обслуживает запросы к этому сайту.

то есть одно из двух:

1. поменять принадлежность файлов и каталогов, например, так (исхожу из предположения, что *apache* обслуживает запросы от имени пользователя *www-data*):

   ```
   $ sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/www
   ```
2. установить и задействовать модуль *mpm-itk* (скрее всего, имеется в репозитории вашего дистрибутива в пакете под схожим названием, например, *apache2-mpm-itk*) и внутри блоков *virtualhost* добавить директивы примерно такого вида:

   ```
   assignuserid пользователь-владелец группа-владелец
   ```

   подробности смотрите в документации, прилагающейся к этому пакету, либо на [сайте разработчиков](http://mpm-itk.sesse.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Точного ответа дать не могу, но так устроена система.
Все дело в [umask](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) выставляемой системой для пользователя.
Проверить не могу, но предположительно это опция задается при компиляции ядра.
Странно конечно, что у Вас новому файлу дается 700, как минимум должно быть 600, в моем случае 644.

Можно использовать алиасы или пойти простым путем:

```
echo 'umask 0' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Не забудьте перелогиниться.
Для Вашего случая этого более чем достаточно.

Comment: очень похоже на неверное решение [неверно поставленной задачи](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710/178576).

Comment: Это Ваше сугубо-личное мнение. Мой ответ решает проблему пользователя.

Comment: создание пользователем **всех** файлов и каталогов с правами `ugo=rwx` — это неправильное решение. равно как и присвоение всем файлам/каталогам в docroot-е таких прав. по-моему, корень проблемы в том, что http-сервер у автора вопроса работает от имени пользователя, отличного от того, кому принадлежат файлы/каталоги в docroot-е. решать стоит именно эту проблему, а не последствия попытки решить её неправильно.

Answer (score 0):

Апачу новый файл доступен для чтения, обычно этого достаточно.

Если же нужен полный доступ, кроме упомянутого модуля mpm-itk есть ещё два решения.

1. Если apache запускается с правами пользователя www-data, заменить `www-data` в настройках apache на имя пользователя, под которым вы работаете. Имя может задаваться в разных файлах в зависимости от дистрибутива, найти можно с помощью команды `grep -R www-data /etc/apache2/` или рекурсивного поиска в `mc`. После чего необходимо рестартовать apache2. Определить под каким пользователем запущен apache можно с помощью команды `ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'`.
2. Добавить вас в группу, которую использует apache:

   ```
   sudo adduser alice www-data
   ```

   После чего нужно зайти заново в систему. Вам будут доступны файлы группы www-data если у них стоит соответствующий режим для группы (например rw-rw-r--). Но чтобы новые файлы были с таким режимом нужно вам и апачу установить `umask 002`. Кроме того, чтобы новые файлы были в нужной группе, нужно временно сменить группу по-умолчанию:

   ```
   newgrp www-data
   ```

   Запустится новая оболочка с данным gid. Можете себе сделать такой скрипт и запускать его перед работой с файлами http-сервера.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   umask 002
   newgrp www-data
   ```

   Если данный пользователь только для этого и создан, то наверно лучше подойдёт первый вариант, или сделайте группу www-data для пользователя основной:

   ```
   sudo usermod -g www-data alice
   ```

   Тогда `umask 002` достаточно добавить в `~/.profile`.

   Если apache создаёт новые файлы, и они должны быть доступны пользователю, нужно так же поставить `umask 002` в `/etc/apache2/envvars`, если есть такой файл, либо в скрипт запуска и рестартовать апач.